# Logout functionality in android

Tags: android, logout

I am making a kind of social networking app. I am implementing log-out functionality in it.
On Logout button click it should navigate to login screen but instead it is now navigating to the home page screen.I am using the following code for logout..

```
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction("com.package.ACTION_LOGOUT");
  registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         System.out.println("onReceive Log out in progress");
          Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),          Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                                finish();
                }
            }, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 6):

use following for Logout.

```
yourintent.setflag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

It may help you

Comment: I have tried this also.. but again it is navigating to home page screen

Comment: Hi ekjyot finish your home page when you moving forward from homepage activity.

Comment: Hi ekjyot i have updated my answer please try it i am sure it work

Answer (score 4):

Simply give the intent to your login activity and put the flag in intent

```
inten1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

it will clear all the activities and navigate to ur login page.

Comment: I have done that already.it is again navigating to homepage instaed of login screen

Comment: Then you are finishing all activities while navigating to next to activity, you need to check your code, see if there is any finish() line when  you start the activity.

Comment: pass the intnet= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class) and thats it

Comment: Now thats really strange, are you calling the that intent flag? I really have to see code...lol!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a stack problem. You need to handle it. The best solution I found is that keep single activity in stack when your app runs and on log out only login screen will be in stack and if user presses back button, he will see Home screen.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is keeping track of your login state internally, using some sort of global:

```
public boolean loggedin = false;
```

and then in all your activities, override onResume() and finish() if you're logged out:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (!loggedin)
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Toast.makeText(this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

First make these changes to your code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then remove **finish();** written inside your broadcast receiver.
Best of luck.